# Doubts about pointcloud to laser scan

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was referred to this code previously. I have some doubts about this code, like to clarify some of them.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.h"
#include "nodelet/nodelet.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "pcl/point_cloud.h"
#include "pcl_ros/point_cloud.h"
#include "pcl/point_types.h"
#include "pcl/ros/conversions.h"




namespace pointcloud_to_laserscan
{
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;

class CloudToScan : public nodelet::Nodelet
{
public:
  //Constructor
  CloudToScan(): min_height_(0.10), max_height_(0.15), u_min_(100), u_max_(150), output_frame_id_("/openi_depth_frame")
  {
  };

private:
  virtual void onInit()
  {
    ros::NodeHandle& nh = getNodeHandle();
    ros::NodeHandle& private_nh = getPrivateNodeHandle();
    
    private_nh.getParam("min_height", min_height_);
    private_nh.getParam("max_height", max_height_);

    private_nh.getParam("row_min", u_min_);
    private_nh.getParam("row_max", u_max_);

    private_nh.getParam("output_frame_id", output_frame_id_);
    pub_ = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("scan", 10);
    sub_ = nh.subscribe<PointCloud>("cloud", 10, &CloudToScan::callback, this);
  };

  void callback(const PointCloud::ConstPtr& cloud)
  {
    sensor_msgs::LaserScanPtr output(new sensor_msgs::LaserScan());
    NODELET_DEBUG("Got cloud");
    //Copy Header
    output->header = cloud->header;
    output->header.frame_id = output_frame_id_;
    output->angle_min = -M_PI/2;
    output->angle_max = M_PI/2;
    output->angle_increment = M_PI/180.0/2.0;
    output->time_increment = 0.0;
    output->scan_time = 1.0/30.0;
    output->range_min = 0.45;
    output->range_max = 10.0;
    
    uint32_t ranges_size = std::ceil((output->angle_max - output->angle_min) / output->angle_increment);
    output->ranges.assign(ranges_size, output->range_max + 1.0);

    //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
    //pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, cloud);
    
    for (PointCloud::const_iterator it = cloud->begin(); it != cloud->end(); ++it)
    {
      const float &x = it->x;
      const float &y = it->y;
      const float &z = it->z;
    
    /*    for (uint32_t u = std::max((uint32_t)u_min_, 0U); u < std::min((uint32_t)u_max_, cloud.height - 1); u++)
      for (uint32_t v = 0; v < cloud.width -1; v++)
      {
        //NODELET_ERROR("%d %d,  %d %d", u, v, cloud.height, cloud.width);
        pcl::PointXYZ point = cloud.at(v,u); ///WTF Column major?
        const float &x = point.x;
        const float &y = point.y;
        const float &z = point.z;
    */  

      if ( std::isnan(x) || std::isnan(y) || std::isnan(z) )
      {
        NODELET_DEBUG("rejected for nan in point(%f, %f, %f)\n", x, y, z);
        continue;  
      }
      if (-y > max_height_ || -y < min_height_)
      {
        NODELET_DEBUG("rejected for height %f not in range (%f, %f)\n", x, min_height_, max_height_);
        continue;
      }
      double angle = -atan2(x, z);
      if (angle < output->angle_min || angle > output->angle_max)
      {
        NODELET_DEBUG("rejected for angle %f not in range (%f, %f)\n", angle, output->angle_min, output->angle_max);
        continue;
      }
      int index = (angle - output->angle_min) / output->angle_increment;
      //printf ("index xyz( %f %f %f) angle %f index %d\n", x, y, z, angle, index);
      double range_sq = z*z+x*x;
      if (output->ranges[index] * output->ranges[index] > range_sq)
        output->ranges[index] = sqrt(range_sq);
      
      
      }
    
    pub_.publish(output);
  }


  double min_height_, max_height_;
  int32_t u_min_, u_max_;
  std::string output_frame_id_;

  ros::Publisher pub_;
  ros::Subscriber sub_;
  
};


PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(pointcloud_to_laserscan, CloudToScan, pointcloud_to_laserscan::CloudToScan, nodelet::Nodelet);
}
```

1. where does the M_PI/2 in the angle_min and angle_max come from?
2. why is it range_sq = x^2 + z^2? shldnt it be range_sq = y^2 + z^2?

correct me if i am wrong.. if x is the horizontal and y is the vertical, then z shld be in the negative direction(coming out of the image plane? hence i think x i vertical and y is horizontal.

3. there is another code called cloud_throttle. Is it necessary to add both together.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10595/doubts-about-pointcloud-to-laser-scan/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1.) M_PI was likely #defined as 3.141592 (pi) in one of the header files.  Somewhere in ROS.

2.) I think the input cloud is defined in a camera frame.  Camera frames are (annoyingly) different than the standard ROS frame.  X is horizontal along the image, Y is vertical along the image (often facing down), and Z is positive going into the image plane.  So here distance to point ahead is z and distance from center is x.

In response to your edit, as stated in [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#axis-orientation), the camera coordinate frame is "z forward, x right, y down", assuming you are looking from the image sensor to the image plane and are centered at the optical focus point of the camera.

3.) No, it's not.  However, if you are running these nodes on a slower computer, the throttling can help a lot.  It's just a very timing-imprecise node to slow things down so that you don't have to process every pointcloud.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-18**:
1 more qn:if (output->ranges[index] * output->ranges[index] > range_sq) output->ranges[index] = sqrt(range_sq);, what is this statement trying to do.. not that sure...

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-07-17**:
The "y" axis is technically the one we're revolving around in camera frame.  Since it's pointing down, the angle rotates the wrong direction.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-17**:
1 more qn: why is it -atan2(x, z)? and not atan2(x,z)?

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-17**:
Thanks a lot for correcting my mistake. Now i understand why it is z*z + x*x

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-14**:
I edited my question.have a look..

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-14**:
M_PI should actually be in a std library header, likely math.h or cmath. It is indeed a macro that is #define'd to 3.14159... I believe some ROS header somewhere pulls in math.h.